# drools: how to edit a .drl file to use that business rules in java or c#

Tags: drools

In concret I will use in c#.

I am looking for an editor of drl file, I know the existence of pluggin in eclipse to edit it but I would like to know if we have something similar in Atom Editor or online web page.

Answer (score 1):

You do have an official web editor for rules, processes and so on. Its name is drools-workbench (if you are using Drools 6.x) or guvnor (if you are using Drools 5.x).

**drools-workbench**: http://www.drools.org/download/download.html (You can also find a docker for drools-workbench image in that webpage).

**Guvnor**: http://download.jboss.org/drools/release/5.6.0.Final/guvnor-distribution-5.6.0.Final.zip

Hope it helps,